# Sanity.io - Add custom date to slug url

Tags: gatsby, sanity

I'm building a Gatsby portfolio site with a [Sanity](https://www.sanity.io/) back-end. The homepage of the site is going to feature a grid of tiles which link through to blog posts. I want the blog post URLS to have the following structure:

**'blog/[*publishedDate*]/[*slugifiedTitle*]'** e.g - 'blog/2019-10-15/my-first-post'

I have achieved this already by getting the PublishedDate and Slug via GraphQL and using a Javascript function on the front-end to concatenate them together and format the URL. However the Tile Grid React component which I use for layout of this section could potentially be used for non-Blog content. Therefore I was wondering how to do this formatting of the URL within Sanity, passing through a slug which already has the format above.

I'm guessing I might be able to achieve this through a custom slugify function as shown [here](https://www.sanity.io/docs/slug-type) but I'm not sure how/if its possible to reference another schema type from within the schema definition for the Slug?

Any pointers on this would be a great help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Solution using `date-fns` for date formatting:

```
{
  name: "slug",
  title: "Slug",
  type: "slug",
  options: {
    source: (doc) => {
      const date = format(new Date(doc.publishedAt), "yyyy/MM/dd");
      return `/blog/${date}/${doc.title}`;
    },
    slugify: (input) =>
      input.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, "-").slice(0, 200),
  },
},
```